# Web3.eth.getGasPrice not working on zkSync?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, web3js, layer-2

I m trying to estimate what is current gas price with Web3.js library on zkSync layer2 network however I m constantly getting same result: 250000000 for multiple days so I assume it s not working correctly. Is web3.js not working with zkSync?
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=getGasPrice#getgasprice

```
const Web3 = require("web3"); // Web3 library
const web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.era.zksync.io");
let gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
```

Comment: Why do you want to estimate the gas price, and not the minimum gas price for a transaction?

Comment: Hmm I thought it's the same. So what is actually getGasPrice giving me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getGasPrice()` returns the median gas price (calculated from previous few blocks).
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getgasprice

You can retrieve that by:

```
const result = await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(result, 'ether'))
```

As to why its `250000000`, that's because that's the `baseFeePerGas` set: https://github.com/matter-labs/foundry-zksync#get-latest-block

---

If you want to estimate the gas price for a transaction you want to make, you can use the `estimateGas` function.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#estimategas

You can do something like:

```
const gasAmount = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    to: toAddress,
    from: fromAddress,
    value: web3.utils.toWei(`${amount}`, 'ether'),
})
```

The input to `estimateGas` function is a transaction object.

---

To add a bit further to this answer,

1. The base fee per gas (lets call it X) is the fee per unit gas. This value is not going to change (unless its modified in the protocol).
2. The amount of gas (lets call it Y) required per transaction will vary depending on the transaction.

```
total fee = amount of gas * fee per unit gas = Y * X
```

Which is why I recommended to use `estimateGas()` function.

Comment: alright, I see. For my script the median price should be good enough. I just want to stop the script from running in case prices are too high. So any idea why getGasPrice always shows the same value here? I tried also with ethers library and the result is always 250000000.

Comment: `250000000` is the `baseFeePerGas` https://github.com/matter-labs/foundry-zksync#get-latest-block

Comment: Thanks for help Robin. Unfortunately, it's still not clear for me what are the implications of that in my context. So if getGasPrice returns 250000000 because its a baseFeePerGas. Will it rise if the prices of gas increase in a given moment or will it always be the same value?
My goal is to pause the transaction once the cost of transaction rises above some threshold. Would estimateGas be a better solution here?

Comment: @Yogurt33 I have updated my answer to add further details at the end. And yes, you should be using `estimateGas`.